# Trouble solving extremely simple integration by parts

Tags: calculus, integration

This is a very basic question so it's kind of embarrassing but I can't seem for the life of me to get the right answer for some reason.

I want to find $\int\frac{x}{(1+x)^2}dx=\int x\frac{1}{(1+x)^2}dx$

Let $u(x)=x$ and $v'(x)=\frac{1}{(1+x)^2}$, it follows that $u'(x)=1$ and $v(x)=-\frac{1}{1+x}$

We know that $\int u(x)v'(x)dx=u(x)v(x)-\int v(x)u'(x)dx$

So:

$\int u(x)v'(x)dx = \int x\frac{1}{(1+x)^2}dx=-x\frac{1}{1+x}-\int-\frac{1}{1+x}dx=-\frac{x}{1+x}+\ln(1+x)$

but $\frac{d}{dx}\left(-\frac{x}{1+x}+\ln(1+x)\right)\neq \frac{x}{(1+x)^2}$

So we found the wrong answer, but I can't for the life of me find where I went wrong. I must have overlooked a silly mistake somewhere because this should be very easy

Comment: You did everything right, and found the right answer.  The derivative of your answer does indeed equal $\frac{x}{(1+x)^2}$.

Comment: I thought so too, but according to wolfram,The correct answer should be $\frac{1}{x+1}+\ln(x+1)$.

Comment: Alt Method: Take $1+x=t$ Then your integral becomes $$\int\frac{x}{(1+x)^2}dx=\int \frac{t-1}{t^2}dt$$

Comment: @OriaGruber, if you subtract the "correct answer by wolfram" from the "correct answer by Oria", you will find the difference is a constant.

Comment: That's so silly...Make an answer so I can close this please :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The OP has the correct answer.  It only appears incorrect because wolfram's answer differs by a constant.